# Is that a problem that my visa is not from Italian embassy

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I have six days academic visit to Germany in August, 6 Days in Prague in September,  15 days in September in Italy, I have been recently granted a 10-month Multiple entries Schengen visa (Type C, with 90 days maximum stay per journey)  by the German embassy, valid from Aug 2019.

While applying for this visa with German embassy, I showed them invitation letter from German university as well as the Italian University but I didn't show them the invitation letter from Prague as it came late and I was not sure whether I will be invited at all.

In each journey, I will go from the home and the return home, I mean the itinerary will be H--G--H, H--P-H, H-I-H, H=Home, G=Germany, P=Prague, I=Italy.

(1) Is that a problem that I didn't apply for a visa with the Italian embassy as I am staying the maximum number of days there.

(2)  Is that a problem that I didn't submit an invitation letter from Prague to the German embassy?

Comment: Seems fine to me, if you're making separate trips and the first one is to Germany. It would not be unusual for an academic visitor to go to different countries in each trip using a multiple entry visa.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation! Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things function slightly differently for **multiple-entry, 90/180** visa.

- You are not given 90 days per trip. You have 90 days out of 180 days with a "sliding window." Any day you plan to be in the Schengen area, count back 180 days from that day. You must have been in Schengen for no more than 90 of those days. (It is smart to leave a few days reserve, it case you have to transit through Schengen later.)
- The first trip must be for the purpose that was stated in the application. Any subsequent trips can be for other purposes, even tourism.